# Writing Files on Hadoop Line by line using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I'm working with files which has varying schema for lines, so i need to parse each line and take decisions basis that which needs me write files to HDFS line by line.

Is there a way to achieve that in python?

Comment: Pyspark writes a dataframe, but dataframes typically have a common schema as a whole. Writing "line by line" to HDFS doesn't work that well because it's not meant to be used for file appends

Answer (score 4):

You can use IOUtils from `sc._gateway.jvm` and use it to stream from one hadoop file(or local) to file on hadoop.

```
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
fs = FileSystem.get(Configuration())
IOUtils = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils
f = fs.open(Path("/user/test/abc.txt"))
output_stream = fs.create(Path("/user/test/a1.txt"))
IOUtils.copyBytes(f, output_stream, Configuration())
```